# Как убрать резкость при откате hover scale?

Tags: html, css

Для меня существует такая проблема:
При наведении на картинку она увеличиваться при помощи `scale(1.3)`
Но когда убираешь курсок, то картинка уменьшается резко, как сделать что бы картинка так же плавно уменьшалась, как и увеличивается?

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/530407429390209025/jUyFR-5L.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  transition: transform .3s;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform .3s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/530407429390209025/jUyFR-5L.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Можно убрать в :hover - transition, работает также))

Comment: @St1myL Я в курсе, но если понадобиться сдела с разной скоростью?

Comment: мало ли, решил подсказать, не сочти за наглость))

Comment: @St1myL ))))))))